# Creating an own collection class in c#

Tags: c#, collections

I am a new c# developer and im on the learning curve on c#. Now, i have an very small project where I should write my own generic list class for storing data. Im not allowed to use any of the .NET collection classes. My class should have methods for adding/removing items and properties for the number of items from the list. Since im not allowed to use any of the .NET colection classes, my list should be stored in an array in my class.

So, what have I done so far? Since I have no Idea on how to start, I just wrote down the methods that will be used to get a vision of what I should do next:

```
public class myList
{
    public void addItem()
    {

    }

    public void removeItem()
    {

    }
}
```

Now, Im pretty lost, what should I do next?

Comment: You can almost use Interfaces ? If yes implement IList interface.

Comment: Have a look at how the .Net collection classes work with a decompiler - either Red-Gate Reflector or Jetbrains Dotpeek should do the trick

Comment: Adding an item means:
Creating a new array with itemcount + 1 of the old array and copying the old contents in the new array.
Removing means, creating a new array with itemcount - 1 and skip copying of the content at the specific index.
This shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: as an aside, I noticed you have some great responses to previous questions but you haven't accepted any of your answers.  You should.

Comment: Given the arbitrary requirement of not being able to use .NET collection claasses you might want to read the series of articles in [An Extensive Examination of Data Structures Using C# 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830851(v=vs.80).aspx). It should give you idea of some of the requirements of your collection that you haven't considered.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you read up on how to use arrays on MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx.  Generally it is bad form to ask the community to essentially write the code for you, but here are some pointers:

- Write a constructor to initialize the list with an array of objects, e.g. `public myListClass(object[] items)`
- Your addItem class should pass the object you are trying to add, so: `public void addItem(object newItem)`
- Your removeItem should have a couple of different overloads so that you can determine what you want to remove.  e.g. `remoteItem(int itemIndex)`, `removeItem(string itemKey)` or `removeItem(object item)`
- You will probably want to store the current size of the array as a private variable and increment this by 1 each time you add an item.  You then declare a new array of the larger size and copy the original items into it.  Copy the new item last.
- You may also want a sort method, but this will depend entirely on how complex the objects are that will be stored in the array.
- You probably don't have to reduce the size of the array when removing items though you may find it necessary to count the number of items etc.  If you don't reduce the size of the array every time an item is removed be sure to take this into account when adding items (since it may already be large enough).
- Write a count() method that returns the number of items in the array - use this to check for null values if you don't reduce the array's size when removing items.

There are a ton of other considerations, not least of which is using generics to allow multiple types to be stored.  I suggest a little reading around the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/512aeb7t.aspx

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the items in your "List" in an array (a private member of your class).

The problem is that an array has a fixed size (you can't just add items to it). So you need to give it some initial size and remember how "full" it is. When you need more space, you need to create a new, larger array and copy items over from the original one.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, not particularly elegant but a starting point none the less and it doesn't use .net collection classes

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        myList<int> lst = new myList<int>();
        lst.addItem(10);
        lst.addItem(20);
        lst.addItem(30);

        foreach (var i in lst.getItems())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        lst.removeItem(20);

        foreach (var i in lst.getItems())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}


public class myList <T>
{
    private T[] items = new T[0];

    public void addItem(T item)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref items, items.Count() + 1);
        items[items.Count()-1] = item;
    }

    public void removeItem(T item)
    {
        items[Array.IndexOf(items, item)] = items[items.Count() - 1];
        Array.Resize(ref items, items.Count() -1);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `removeItem` just removes the last item in the list. You'll need to find it in the list and swap it with the last item (for an easy solution)

Comment: great spot, and nice easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

A simple collection isn't that hard to implement, but you would need to make the following:

An array to hold the data. Using generics, it could be something like `private T[] data = new T[10];`.
This will of course limit the size to 10, but this can be changed :-)

Generic methods. Something like `public T GetItem(int index){...}`

Also if you know how, it might be great to have an indexer. You can google that :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `linked list` in C#.

Check this out:
http://csharp-algos.blogspot.com/2010/09/blog-post.html

This is the standard way of doing this without any .NET libraries