# Expand an array with a method, c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array that I have predefined to have a length of 2.

```
private int[] numbers = new int[2];
```

Now, I want to write a method that creates an array with double size of its current state and copy all the data to it. Then it assigns the array reference to this new one. Any ideas on how I should start with the method?

Comment: You can't ask a different SO question everytime you need to do something. Try and do some stuff yourself, then present SO with the problem that your coming across.

Comment: What is this? Crowdsource a generic collection? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063800/working-with-predefined-arrays, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063366/creating-an-own-collection-class-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to do this yourself - it already exists, in [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx):

```
Array.Resize(ref numbers, numbers.Length * 2);
```

Comment: Do we really want to encourage develpment like this?

Comment: I gave him a solution 30 minutes ago which included array.Resize, guess he doesn't read answers...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063366/creating-an-own-collection-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: @MitchWheat: I'm torn. On the one hand, I don't think the OP has acted well. On the other hand, I can see this potentially being a useful question/answer pair for other people who are unaware of `Array.Resize`. (The opposite of the normal "too localized" kind of situation.) I'll leave this answer for the moment, but if the whole question ends up getting closed and then deleted, I won't shed a tear...